# How to Improve This Program, Add Comments, etc.?

Tags: python, optimization, database

Do you have any suggestions to improve or extend this script? Any ideas for removing or adding comments/docstrings?

```
import dbm
import subprocess
import time
subprocess.call("clear")
try:
    # Tries to import cPickle, a faster implementation of pickle.
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

class PickleDB:
    def open_db(self):
        """Gets and opens the database"""
        self.db_name = input("Enter a database name\n")
        # Makes sure the database name is compatible
        db_parts = self.db_name.split(".")
        self.db_name = db_parts[0]
        self.db = dbm.open(self.db_name, "n")

    def get_data(self):
        """Gets data to write into the database"""
        subprocess.call("clear")
        self.raw_data = input("Enter your raw data\n")
        # Pickles data
        self.pickled_data = pickle.dumps(self.raw_data)

    def write_to_db(self):
        """Writes data into database"""
        # Logs time
        self.start = time.time()
        # Creates keys
        self.db["raw"] = self.raw_data
        self.db["pickled"] = self.pickled_data

    def close_db(self):
        """Closes database"""
        self.db.close()
        # Logs end time
        self.end = time.time()

    def info(self):
        """Prints out info about the database"""
        subprocess.call("clear")
        print("Load data from database using dbm")
        print("Keys: raw\tpickled")
        # Prints total time
        print("Speed:", self.end - self.start, "seconds")

# Function calls
pickled_db = PickleDB()
pickled_db.open_db()
pickled_db.get_data()
pickled_db.write_to_db()
pickled_db.close_db()
pickled_db.info()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import dbm
import subprocess
import time
subprocess.call("clear")
```

This isn't cross-platform. Sadly, there isn't really a cross-platform alternative

```
try:
    # Tries to import cPickle, a faster implementation of pickle.
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

class PickleDB:
    def open_db(self):
        """Gets and opens the database"""
        self.db_name = input("Enter a database name\n")
```

You really shouldn't call `input` inside of a work class. The code responsible for User I/O should be separate from that doing any actual work.

```
        # Makes sure the database name is compatible
        db_parts = self.db_name.split(".")
        self.db_name = db_parts[0]
```

Ok, why are you ignoring part of the name if its not good? Shouldn't you complain to the user and ask for a new name? Also, I'd avoid assigning to `self.db_name` only the replace it again a bit later. Since you don't use it outside this function, I'd probably just have a local variable

```
        self.db = dbm.open(self.db_name, "n")

    def get_data(self):
        """Gets data to write into the database"""
        subprocess.call("clear")
        self.raw_data = input("Enter your raw data\n")
        # Pickles data
```

This comment is a little obvious, I'd delete it

```
        self.pickled_data = pickle.dumps(self.raw_data)
```

I'd expect a function that `gets` data to return it to the caller. Generally, functions that drop state onto the class is a sign of poor design. Methods should usually communicate by parameters and return values not object storage.

```
    def write_to_db(self):
        """Writes data into database"""
        # Logs time
        self.start = time.time()
```

Collecting timing information isn't something that's usually part of the actual class doing the work. Usually you'd time the class from the outside.

```
        # Creates keys
        self.db["raw"] = self.raw_data
        self.db["pickled"] = self.pickled_data

    def close_db(self):
        """Closes database"""
        self.db.close()
        # Logs end time
        self.end = time.time()


    def info(self):
        """Prints out info about the database"""
        subprocess.call("clear")
        print("Load data from database using dbm")
        print("Keys: raw\tpickled")
        # Prints total time
        print("Speed:", self.end - self.start, "seconds")
```

As noted, output and timing is usually something you want to do outside of the work class itself.

```
# Function calls
pickled_db = PickleDB()
pickled_db.open_db()
pickled_db.get_data()
pickled_db.write_to_db()
pickled_db.close_db()
pickled_db.info()
```

Here's the overall thing about your code. You are using a class as a group of functions and treating the object storage like a place to put global variables. You aren't making effective use of the class. In this case, you'd be better off to use a collection of functions than a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think Winston Ewert summed up quite well what is wrong with the code. You should replace all that is after the line `# Function calls` by

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pickle_db = PickleDB(input("Enter a database name\n"))
    pickle_db.write(input("Enter your raw data\n"))
    pickle_db.close()
    print("Speed:{0} seconds".format(pickle_db.get_total_time())
```

and build your class from that snippet of code (put the open function in the init, for example)